# Should the verb be singular or plural with 'months' 'hours' 'days' etc?

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural

Three to six months *is/are* enough for preparation.
Singular verb or plural and why?

Comment: It depends on the sentence, on the context, and on the register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Three to six months *is* enough (time) for preparation.

Time is implied, so it has to be "is." A native speaker wouldn't say "they are enough time," but they might say "it's enough time."